# Lodash group by multiple properties if property value is true

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of vehicles that need to be grouped by make and model, only if the 'selected' property is true. The resulting object should contain properties for make model and count. Using lodash, how can I organize the vehicle objects into the desired result objects. I'm able to get the vehicle objects grouped by makeCode but I'm not sure how to group by more than one property.

***group by make code works***

```
      var vehicles = _.groupBy(response.vehicleTypes, function(item)
      {
        return item.makeCode; // how to group by model code as well
      });
```

***initial vehicles***

```
{
    id: 1, 
    selected: true, 
    makeCode: "Make-A", 
    modelCode: "Model-a", 
    trimCode: "trim-a", 
    yearCode: "2012"
},
{
    id: 2, 
    selected: false, 
    makeCode: "Make-A", 
    modelCode: "Model-a", 
    trimCode: "trim-a", 
    yearCode: "2013"
},
{
    id: 3, 
    selected: true, 
    makeCode: "Make-B", 
    modelCode: "Model-c", 
    trimCode: "trim-a", 
    yearCode: "2014"
},
{
    id: 25, 
    selected: true, 
    makeCode: "Make-C", 
    modelCode: "Model-b", 
    trimCode: "trim-b", 
    yearCode: "2012"
},
{
    id: 26, 
    selected: true, 
    makeCode: "Make-C", 
    modelCode: "Model-b", 
    trimCode: "trim-a", 
    yearCode: "2013"
}
```

***result object***

```
{
    Make-A: {
        Model-a: {
            count: 1
        }
    }
},

{
    Make-B: {
        Model-c: {
            count: 1
        }
    }
},
{
    Make-C: {
        Model-b: {
            count: 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how about when there is a Make -T with Model-X and Model-Y

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Since you're already using lodash, you can take advantage of the [_.filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#filter) function. This will return only the items where `selected` is true.

```
var selectedVehicles = _.filter(response.vehicleTypes, 'selected');
```

Now that you have the `selectedVehicles` array, you can use your original code for grouping by the `makeCode`.

```
selectedVehicles = _.groupBy(selectedVehicles, function(item) {
  return item.makeCode;
});
```

This returns an object, so we will need to iterate through those keys, and perform our second `groupBy`

```
_.forEach(selectedVehicles, function(value, key) {
  selectedVehicles[key] = _.groupBy(selectedVehicles[key], function(item) {
    return item.modelCode;
  });
});
```

From this you will have an object of the form. I'll leave it to you to get the count from each array.

```
{ 'Make-A': { 'Model-a': [ ... ] },
  'Make-B': { 'Model-c': [ ... ] },
  'Make-C': { 'Model-b': [ ..., ... ] } }
```

Comment: Thanks for stepping through this, makes perfect sense! I was over thinking it.

Comment: You can use the `property` shorthand and just do `_.groupBy(selectedVehicles, 'makeCode')`

Answer (score 46):

I am not sure if this will solve Your problem, but in group_by You can add custom logic which allow You to create composite key.

Remember that SEPERATOR value should be defined accordingly to data source You work with, if "--" characters occur in model or type You should not used them as it will not allow You to reverse the process of grouping.

```
const SEPERATOR = "--";
_.chain(data).filter((item) => item.selected).groupBy((item)=>`${item.model}${SEPERATOR}${item.type}`).value();
```

Comment: This method is more efficient as we only loop through the items once.

Comment: Genius! Just add `.value()` after .

Comment: nice thats a good idea. Pay attention to the small edge case. Assuming '-' is a valid character. this object `{model:'---', type:'-'}` and this object `{model:'--',type:'--'}` will be grouped although they don't have the same model and type

Comment: Hi @yonBav You have a point here that a constant variable should be used to keep the separator value and this is as well important to do reverse the grouping process or access the model or type information from dictionary key.

Comment: But @yonBav I don't agree with Your example case, the value of separator has to be selected in accordance with data You work on. The example snippet is just showing how the problem may be solved. A data context was not considered.

Comment: Agreed, I think it's a very good solution. I only wanted to point that you need to pick your separator carefully

Comment: @IOR88 Use the property shorthand `groupBy(item.model + SEPERATOR + item.type)`

Answer (score 22):

Following code works if you focus on result:

in my case, `Brand` and `Item Code` are properties

```js
const products = _.groupBy(this.productsTable.data, (item) => {
    return [item['Brand'], item['Item Code']];
});
```

Comment: good answer. if only you had taken 10 seconds more to actually notice the output format he asked is different :)

Comment: Not everyone drop here come with exact same problem as mentioned in question. This answer is for those cases. @Dheeraj

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), and do it in one loop O(n):

```js
var arr = [{"id":1,"selected":true,"makeCode":"Make-A","modelCode":"Model-a","trimCode":"trim-a","yearCode":"2012"},{"id":2,"selected":false,"makeCode":"Make-A","modelCode":"Model-a","trimCode":"trim-a","yearCode":"2013"},{"id":3,"selected":true,"makeCode":"Make-B","modelCode":"Model-c","trimCode":"trim-a","yearCode":"2014"},{"id":25,"selected":true,"makeCode":"Make-C","modelCode":"Model-b","trimCode":"trim-b","yearCode":"2012"},{"id":26,"selected":true,"makeCode":"Make-C","modelCode":"Model-b","trimCode":"trim-a","yearCode":"2013"},{"id":29,"selected":false,"makeCode":"Make-A","modelCode":"Model-g","trimCode":"trim-a","yearCode":"2013"},{"id":2,"selected":true,"makeCode":"Make-A","modelCode":"Model-h","trimCode":"trim-a","yearCode":"2013"}];

var result = arr.reduce(function(map, obj) {
  if(!obj.selected) {
    return map;
  }
  
  var makeCode = map[obj.makeCode] = map[obj.makeCode] || {};
  
  var modelCode = makeCode[obj.modelCode] = makeCode[obj.modelCode] || { count: 0 };
  
  modelCode.count++;
  
  return map;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

A more readable, and modern version using destructuring:

```js
const arr = [{"id":1,"selected":true,"makeCode":"Make-A","modelCode":"Model-a","trimCode":"trim-a","yearCode":"2012"},{"id":2,"selected":false,"makeCode":"Make-A","modelCode":"Model-a","trimCode":"trim-a","yearCode":"2013"},{"id":3,"selected":true,"makeCode":"Make-B","modelCode":"Model-c","trimCode":"trim-a","yearCode":"2014"},{"id":25,"selected":true,"makeCode":"Make-C","modelCode":"Model-b","trimCode":"trim-b","yearCode":"2012"},{"id":26,"selected":true,"makeCode":"Make-C","modelCode":"Model-b","trimCode":"trim-a","yearCode":"2013"},{"id":29,"selected":false,"makeCode":"Make-A","modelCode":"Model-g","trimCode":"trim-a","yearCode":"2013"},{"id":2,"selected":true,"makeCode":"Make-A","modelCode":"Model-h","trimCode":"trim-a","yearCode":"2013"}];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, { selected, makeCode, modelCode }) => {
  if(!selected) return acc;
  
  if(!acc[makeCode]) acc[makeCode] = {};
  
  const make = acc[makeCode];
  
  if(!make[modelCode]) make[modelCode] = { count: 0 };
  
  make[modelCode].count++;
  
  return acc;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What does this statement do? `var makeCode = map[obj.makeCode] = map[obj.makeCode] || {};`

Comment: The main idea of my younger in this `var makeCode = map[obj.makeCode] = map[obj.makeCode] || {};` is - assign `map[obj.makeCode]` or and empty  object `{}` to `map[obj.makeCode]` (it's used as fallback in case `map[obj.makeCode]` doesn't exist yet), and assign `map[obj.makeCode]` to `makeCode`. I must admit, it's not the most readable code in the world. I'll tell that to my younger self when I meet him :)

Answer (score 5):

```js
const result = _.chain(vehicles)
.filter('selected')
.groupBy('makeCode')
.mapValues(values => _.chain(values)
    .groupBy('modelCode')
    .mapValues(_.size)
    .value()
)
.value()
```

Comment: I edited your code snippet, but not sure if this is making it any better. Probably it should not be a runnable code snippets if it's not the complete code sample.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const multiGroupBy = (array, group, ...restGroups) => {
  if(!group) {
    return array;
  }
  const currGrouping = _.groupBy(array, group);
  if(!restGroups.length) {
    return currGrouping;
  }
  return _.transform(currGrouping, (result, value, key) => {
    result[key] = multiGroupBy(value, ...restGroups);
  }, {});
};

console.log(multiGroupBy([{x:1,y:1,z:1},{x:1,y:2,z:1},{x:2,y:1,z:1},{x:2,y:2,z:1},{x:1,y:1,z:2},{x:1,y:2,z:2},{x:2,y:1,z:2},{x:2,y:2,z:2}],'x','y'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

or if you prefer old syntax

```js
function multiGroupBy(array, group) {
  if(!group) {
    return array;
  }
  var currGrouping = _.groupBy(array, group);
  var restGroups = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  restGroups.splice(0,2);
  if(!restGroups.length) {
    return currGrouping;
  }
  return _.transform(currGrouping, function(result, value, key) {
    result[key] = multiGroupBy.apply(null, [value].concat(restGroups));
  }, {});
}

console.log(multiGroupBy([{x:1,y:1,z:1},{x:1,y:2,z:1},{x:2,y:1,z:1},{x:2,y:2,z:1},{x:1,y:1,z:2},{x:1,y:2,z:2},{x:2,y:1,z:2},{x:2,y:2,z:2}],'x','y'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

For those you are looking something similar as the owner but don't have a boolean as a filter as first property, you can do a double groupby:

```
export function groupByLodash(results: myType[]) {
  return mapValues(
    groupBy(results, 'property.to.group'),
    (result: myType) => groupBy(result, 'second.property.to.group'),
  );
}
```

the result sould be something like:

```
{
"property.to.group": { "second.property.to.group": {...result}}
}
```

Comment: Ok perfect ! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Grouping and filtering an object or array without LODASH on pure JS:**

```js
// Группировка и фильтрация объекта или массива без LODASH на чистом JS:
let k = "HUID", // group by; 
input = [
{HUID:11,test:1},
{HUID:11,test:111},
{HUID:'eeeeeeeeeeee',test:11111},
{HUID:22,test:2},
{HUID:33,test:3}
],
result = input.reduce((map, obj) => { 
//if(!obj.selected) { return map; } 
let makeCode = (map[obj[k]] = map[obj[k]] || {}); // var modelCode = makeCode[obj.HUID] = makeCode[obj.HUID] || { count: 0 }; 
let l = map[obj[k]],
    m = Object.keys(l).length; 
l[m] = { ...obj }; 
return map; 
}, {} );
console.log(result);
```

[Copied from VK](https://vk.com/topic-125614288_34588945?post=857)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reiterate all the array object. with loadash, you can make simple as below:

```
_.mapValues(_.groupBy(object, 'yourKeys'))
```