# Javascript can't group objects with 2 values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have this object data:

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 59,
    steamid: '76561198220437096',
    product_id: 23,
    status: 1,
    date: 2017-12-18T17:27:19.000Z,
    message: null,
    name: 'CS.MONEY',
    amount: 100,
    website: 'csgo500' },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 60,
    steamid: '76561198220437096',
    product_id: 24,
    status: 1,
    date: 2017-12-18T17:27:19.000Z,
    message: null,
    name: 'CS.MONEY',
    amount: 250,
    website: 'csgo500' },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 61,
    steamid: '76561198220437096',
    product_id: 23,
    status: 1,
    date: 2017-12-18T17:27:19.000Z,
    message: null,
    name: 'CS.MONEY',
    amount: 100,
    website: 'csgo500' },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 62,
    steamid: '76561198345348530',
    product_id: 6,
    status: 1,
    date: 2017-12-18T20:05:55.000Z,
    message: null,
    name: 'wal gruche',
    amount: 100,
    website: 'csgoatse' }
```

Im trying to sort this data with steamid and website, i managed to sort this only by one value like this:

```
    var groupedOrders = {};
    row.forEach(function(item){
                    var list = groupedOrders[item.steamid];

                    if(list){
                        list.push(item);
                    } else{
                       groupedOrders[item.steamid] = [item];
                    }
                });
```

My idea was to make two dimensional array but for some reason i cant do it like this:

```
var list = groupedOrders[item.steamid][item.website];
```

It throws me an error "Cant read property ... of undefined"

Now my code looks like this:

```
 var groupedOrders = {};
            row.forEach(function(item){
                var list = groupedOrders[item.steamid][item.website];

                if(list){
                    list.push(item);
                } else{
                   groupedOrders[item.steamid][item.website] = [item];
                }
            });
```

Do you have any ideas how to fix this errors?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40139667/lodash-group-by-multiple-properties-if-property-value-is-true

Comment: Not particularly clear question. Can you show how you want the data to look after the sort?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `var list = groupedOrders[item.steamid][item.website]` is actually saying:

```
var temp = groupedOrders[item.steamid];
var list = temp[item.website];
```

There is no entry at `groupedOrders[item.steamid]` and so line one sets `temp` to `undefined`. The second line tries to index into `undefined` which is an error.

You would have to split the code out and essentially do the whole one-key grouping twice:

```
var outerList = groupedOrders[item.steamid];
if (!outerList)
    outerList = groupedOrders[item.steamid] = {};
var innerList = outerList[item.website];
if (innerList)
    innerList.push(item);
else
    outerList[item.website] = [item];
```

(I have not tested this code but it is the right shape.)

Answer (score 0):

The following works by creating a recursive `groupBy` grouping function for each of the fields supplied as an argument.

These dynamically created `groupBy` functions are then invoked one by one, passing the result between, starting with the supplied data.

Each `groupBy` function instance creates an object and adds properties to it corresponding to the key values for the field being grouped.

By calling these `groupBy` functions successively, we create a progressively more nested tree of objects, with groups at each successive level marked as being groups using a symbol.

The final result is a nest (a tree!) of objects, with keys corresponding to the field used for indexing at that level.

Finally, we flatten the nest and the final order is visible.

```js
const flatten = o => Object.values(o).reduce((acc, c) => (Array.isArray(c) ? [...acc, ...c] : typeof c === 'object' ? [...acc, ...flatten(c)] : [...acc, c]), []);
const flow = (...fns) => data => fns.reduce((acc, c) => c(acc), data);
const GROUP = Symbol('group');
const asGroup = (result = []) => ((result[GROUP] = true), result);
const isGroup = o => o[GROUP];

const groupBy = field => (data, key) =>
    data.reduce((acc, c) => 
        ((key = c[field]), (acc[key] ? 
            (acc[key].push(c), acc) : 
                ((acc[key] = asGroup([c])), acc))), {});

const recurse = (test) => (transform) => o =>
    test(o)
        ? transform(o)
        : Object.entries(o).reduce(
              (acc, [k, v]) => (test(v) ? 
                  ((acc[k] = transform(v)), acc) : 
                  ((acc[k] = recurse(test)(transform)(v)), acc)), {});
                  
const group = (...fields) => flow(...fields.map(flow(groupBy, recurse(isGroup))), flatten);

const rows = asGroup([
    {
        id: 0,
        steamid: '2',
        website: 'a'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        steamid: '2',
        website: 'b'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        steamid: '2',
        website: 'a'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        steamid: '1',
        website: 'b'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        steamid: '0',
        website: 'b'
    }
]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(group('steamid', 'website')(rows), null, 2));
```