# Multilevel group by using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, lodash

I have below array of objects

```
const array = [
  {
    key: '11111',
    address: { city: 'NY', country: 'USA' },
    className: 'google.com',
    deviceId: 'aaaaa'
  },
  { 
    key: '11111',
    address: { city: 'NY', country: 'USA' },
    className: 'google.com',
    deviceId: 'aaaaa'
  },
  { 
    key: '33333',
    address: { city: 'NY', country: 'USA' },
    className: 'facebook.com',
    deviceId: 'aaaaa'
  },
  { 
    key: '11111',
    address: { city: 'NY', country: 'USA' },
    className: 'google.com',
    deviceId: 'ddddd'
  },
  {
    key: '22222',
    address: { city: 'Landon', country: 'UK' },
    className: 'stackoverflow.com',
    deviceId: 'ccccc'
  },
  {
    key: '22222',
    address: { city: 'Landon', country: 'UK' },
    className: 'stackoverflow.com',
    deviceId: 'ggggg'
  },
  {
    key: '22222',
    address: { city: 'Landon', country: 'UK' },
    className: 'stackoverflow.com',
    deviceId: 'fffff'
  }
]
```

I need the below output

```
[
  {
    "keys": {
      "address": { "city": "NY", "country": "USA" },
      "className": "google.com",
      "key": "11111"
    },
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "keys": {
      "address": { "city": "NY", "country": "USA" },
      "className": "facebook.com",
      "key": "33333"
    },
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "keys": {
      "address": { "city": "Landon", "country": "UK" },
      "className": "stackoverflow.com",
      "key": "22222"
    },
    "count": 3
  }
]
```

So what is really happening here.

**1)** I have to count the user as only one if  the user is with the same `key`, `address`, `className` and `deviceId`.

**and then**

**2)** I want to group with the `key`, `className` and `address` and find the count.

How can I do that?

Thank you!!! Please ask if further information needed.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hmm I was expecting for the same question. I have  tried from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40139667/lodash-group-by-multiple-properties-if-property-value-is-true) but it did not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could chain `groupBy` and `map` methods to first group by key, address, and className and then do one more `groupBy` to group and count elements with unique `deviceId`

```js
const array = [{"key":"11111","address":{"city":"NY","country":"USA"},"className":"google.com","deviceId":"aaaaa"},{"key":"11111","address":{"city":"NY","country":"USA"},"className":"google.com","deviceId":"aaaaa"},{"key":"33333","address":{"city":"NY","country":"USA"},"className":"facebook.com","deviceId":"aaaaa"},{"key":"11111","address":{"city":"NY","country":"USA"},"className":"google.com","deviceId":"ddddd"},{"key":"22222","address":{"city":"Landon","country":"UK"},"className":"stackoverflow.com","deviceId":"ccccc"},{"key":"22222","address":{"city":"Landon","country":"UK"},"className":"stackoverflow.com","deviceId":"ggggg"},{"key":"22222","address":{"city":"Landon","country":"UK"},"className":"stackoverflow.com","deviceId":"fffff"}]

const result = _.chain(array)
  .groupBy(({ key, address: { city, country }, className }) => {
    return `${key}-${city}-${country}-${className}`
  }).map(e => {
    const [{ key, address, className }] = e;
    return {
      keys: { key, address, className },
      count: _.keys(_.groupBy(e, 'deviceId')).length
    }
  })

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: No misunderstood my question. Please have a look at it again. The output does not match.

Comment: Maybe you have mistake in your output, are you also filtering by deviceId?

Comment: Extremely sorry I have updated my question. Please have a look at my two points

Comment: Perfect that is what I wanted. Thank a ton!